# Compare two sql tables available in different database

Tags: boomi

I need to compare a source mysql table data available in one database with target mysql table available in other database in Boomi.

I am not getting the idea on how to compare the whole result-set of one scan with another result-set.

Can anyone please guide to do the dataset comparison in Boomi

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to do that is within a business rule shape. You'll query 1 set of data and put it into a cache with a common index. Then on a branch 2, you will query the 2nd set of data. Next within a business rule you'll compare each field with the cache and if anything changes, you will push it down the accept path.